# edit text focus is not working android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a layout in that EditText is populated dynamically by pressing "Create EditText" Button.

```
    public void onCreateButtonPressed(View view) {
     EditText et = new EditText(this);
     et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
             int id = v.getId();
             Log.d(TAG, "EditText: "+id+"Focus state:"+hasFocus);
         }
     });
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     et.setFocusable(true);
     et.requestFocus();
     et.setId(id++);
     layout.addView(et, params);
 }
```

It is working good. But when i change the focus to some edit text and press "Create EditText" Button then the cursor is blinking in the newly created EditText but the text i typed is not showing the newly created EditText. Searching in Google and SOF gives the usage of requestFocus() function. But i am already using requestFocus() in the newly created EditText.

I am desperately searching the solution for this problem. Any suggestions are welcomed.

-Regards,
Ron

Comment: Can you type in other edittext?

Comment: @Android_Crazy If i create 5 edittexts with this "Create EditText" Button. And when i click on the 2nd edit text ,entered some text and pressed "Create EditText" button a new edit text(6th edit text) is created, and cursor is blinking in the newly created edittext. But the characters i type in the keyboard is going to the 2nd edit text not the newly created edit text. -Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found out the exact problem, in the earlier code i was requesting focus and then adding view to the layout. But we need to do the opposite. First the view needs to be added to the layout and then requestFocus to the edit text. That is solving the problem.

-Regards,
Ron..